# Search filter between promo and exact price

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I've got lots of posts with promotional prices and the rest have an exact price. I just wanted to make sure that if promotional price exists, use the promotional price as the target data when I try to submit a value from the input range else use the real price.

So in my form, I have this slider:

```
<input class="price-select" name="price" value="5000" type="range" min="0" max="5000">
```

and my query looks like this, but it's not working.

```
$args = [
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_query' => []
];

if (isset($date)) {...}

if (isset($destination)) {...}

if (isset($price)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], [
            'key'     => 'promotion_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ]);
        array_push($args['meta_query'], [
            'key'     => 'exact_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ]);
    }

    $getPackages = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This one works fine but it doesn't work with what I wanted, as I can't think of any solution.

I tried using `BETWEEN` and `IN` but it's not working. I'm not sure how it works in this situation.

**Adding more information:**

I've got lots of search filters and the way I added them is by using `array_push`. I tried doing this code below but it affects the other search filter and returned empty. Tried doing the `'relation' => 'OR'`, it works for the rest of the search filters but the price and promotion price are not working.

```
$args = [
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_query' => [
       'relation' => 'AND'
   ]
];
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated! Thanks!

Array dump from `$args`

Without Relation on `meta_query`

```
array(6) {
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(15) "post"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(4)
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(34) "promotion_price"
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "439"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(2) "<="
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(24) "exact_price"
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "439"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(2) "<="
    }
  }
  ["paged"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

With Relation on `meta_query`

```
array(6) {
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(15) "post"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(4)
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(2) "OR"
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(34) "promotion_price"
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "456"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(2) "<="
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(24) "exact_price"
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "456"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(2) "<="
    }
  }
  ["paged"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

All of my array arguments and search filters:

```
$args = [
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => [],
        'meta_query' => [],
        'paged' => 1
];
if (isset($dates)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], [
            'key'     => 'dates',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'value'   => $dates,
        ]);
    }


    if (isset($price)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], [
            'key'     => 'promotion_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ]);
        array_push($args['meta_query'], [
            'key'     => 'exact_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ]);
    }

    if (isset($packages)) {
        foreach ($packages as $package) {
            array_push($args['tax_query'], [
                'taxonomy' => 'tax_1',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $package,
            ]);
        }
    }

    if (isset($durations)) {
        foreach ($durations as $duration) {
            array_push($args['tax_query'], [
                'taxonomy' => 'tax_2',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $duration,
            ]);
        }
    }

    if (isset($departures)) {
        foreach ($departures as $departure) {
            array_push($args['tax_query'], [
                'taxonomy' => 'tax_3',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $departure,
            ]);
        }
    }

$getPackages = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What is `$price`?, you use it but you never declared it. add this `$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` right inside the `if ()` check

Comment: @Buttered_Toast apologies! that should be coming from the `$_GET['price']`. Updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a `print_r` or `var_dump` of your `$args`, I think the relation of all the meta_query (AND/OR) maybe causes unexpected results. You will probably need to nest some of the meta queries

Comment: @Buttered_Toast check my updated post. I've added with and without relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use two or more different meta fields that need to have a relationship bewteen them, you have to provide a value for the `relation` key. This way you can establish the relationship that must be met for your meta fields.

In your specific case, you would use the relation `AND` to make sure that the value of `$price` is greater or equal than the promotion price but also (read AND) lower or equal than the exact price.

So according to your question "Search filter **between** promo and exact price" your `meta_query` array will look something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'promotion_price',
        'value'   => $price,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'exact_price',
        'value'   => $price,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    )
),
```

Extract from the [WP Meta Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) docs:

> You can optionally pass the `relation` key and set it to either OR or AND. It defines the relation, when there is more than one meta query (whether all of the conditions should be met, or at least one of them needs to be met)

### Using multiple nested meta queries

You can also nest multiple meta queries having multiple relation keys. So you can create different conditional blocks. For example, to **ignore** the `promotion_price` key if it does not exist, but use it if it exists:

```
'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'promotion_price',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'exact_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'promotion_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'exact_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    )
),
```

And if you have more conditionals, you can keep on nesting them following the same structure. At each level you will have one `'relation' => 'OR/AND'` with two or more arrays.

Comment: I've tried this one already but it affects the rest of the search filters I have. I updated my post, sorry about missing some information.

Comment: @the_lorem_ipsum_guy Please provide all of your search filters (date, destination, ...). I updated the answer to show an example with nested meta queries.

Comment: Updated my post. Tried this one and some posts were not displayed when I selected a value let's say a price of 400 and some of the post that shown which I noticed that has a `promotion_price` is now empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: @the_lorem_ipsum_guy Now that you know how to create nested conditionals, try to make one with all the possible conditions that you need. Copy the example I provided and add/edit everything you need. Try to do it with hardcoded values, so that we can see exactly what all of your conditions are and how you need them.

Comment: no worries man! thanks for the help. really appreciate it. Will also accept this as an answer as the only thing I need to do is do some tweaks.

Comment: @the_lorem_ipsum_guy Great, if you get stuck feel free to update your question with new information. Good day!